# What is the difference (and similarity if any) between LocalCache and TempState application data folders?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp

A UWP app uses a number of data folders located under a unique folder identified by its package ID. Specifically, how do the LocalCache and TempState data folders compare and contrast?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the desktop, data files for Windows Store apps are stored under the folder **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages{PackageId}** where **{PackageId}** corresponds to the Windows Store app package identifier (a slightly different but similarly unique folder on Windows Mobile).

There are about half a dozen folders, each of these with specific purpose, including folders **LocalCache** intended for caching app data and **TempState** intended as a temp folder.

Here is how the two data folders compare and contrast.

- Both are excluded from backup/restore operations. In contrast, app data folders such as **LocalState**, **Settings** and **RoamingState** are always backed up.
- Both can be deleted any time within an app by using the all clear [and *dangerous*!] method `ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync()`, or selectively using `ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync(ApplicationDataLocality.Temporary)` for **TempState** folder, and `ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync(ApplicationDataLocality.LocalCache)` for **LocalCache** folder.
- **LocalCache** folder can be relied upon until it's deleted, whereas **TempState** folder cannot be relied upon at a later time as it's subject to deletion by external factors such as disk clean-up, or by the operating system on running low on storage space.
- If you want data that doesn't need to be backed up, but want to use it at a later time and only delete it when done with it, then use the **LocalCache** folder.
- If you want data that doesn't need to be backed up, but only needed for the current app session (and leave the cleaning job to external tools such as storage clean-up ) then use the **TempState** folder.
- You may like to implement an automatic clearing of the **TempState** folder upon exiting an app. Likewise, monitoring the **LocalCache** folder for clearing data that is no more needed is an important point to bear mind.